# Google Cloud Platform credentials page not loading

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For the past 12 or so hours when I go here:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=MYPROJECTNAME

I just get the spinning / loading animation.  I have tried other browsers and other computers to no avail.  I just need to add another OATH key.  Is the service somehow broken?  Is there something else I can do?

The browser shows some errors.

Refused to display 'https://apikeys.clients6.google.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&js [ stuff deleted]  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

and a few 404s

cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/PAN_NOTIFICATION_BELL_LAST_OPENED?key=[deleted]:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

like it's able to load the front end but not access the data it needs.

Comment: Hey did you manage to fix this yet?

Comment: I have NOT.  I tried normal mode, incognito mode, disabled every one of my Chrome plugins, then on this same computer tried Internet Explorer and Edge.  Then I tried it on my work computer (using Remote Desktop) and it works there.  I'm completely stumped.  The chrome debugger is reporting 404s trying to get 

 https://cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/PAN_NOTIFICATION_BELL_LAST_OPENED

Comment: I also deleted all cookies and cleared the Chrome cache.  The other strange thing that's super weird is if I navigate to a specific API then select a credential from there, I can actually see them all.  Just not through the normal credentials page, that just hangs and never loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's a Google issue, just got a response back from Google:

Description:
We are experiencing elevated latency in the API Credentials page of Google
Developers Console beginning at 2019-02-09 20:06 PST.

We are using the external issue tracker as the main communication channel
to provide updates on this issue. Please star the issue here to receive
further updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/124188941.

This Issue Tracker entry is the authoritative source for public information
regarding this issue. All publicly-applicable updates will be posted there.

How to diagnose:
1. Visit Google Developers Console.
2. Select "APIs & Services".
3. Select "Credentials".

Result: Credentials page will continuously load.

Workaround:
There's no workaround available at this time, but we'll let you know via
the external issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/124188941) if
we learn of one.

Comment: Falko thanks for facilitating, a lot of people were experiencing this according to that ticket and this evening Google finally resolved the problem.